# Geoserver CQL Cross Layer Intersection Failing

Tags: geoserver, wfs, filter, cql-filter

I am having trouble forming a properly formatted CQL request using geoServer cross layer filer functions and was hoping others could assist. My request is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=AU:TownPoints&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom,collectGeometries(queryCollection('AU:Districts','the_geom','CODE=A1')))&version=1.1.0
```

The intent is to select the towns that are within a selected District shape.

With the above request a null data set is returned:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:AU="hidden.com" xmlns:tiger="http://www.census.gov" xmlns:cite="http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite" xmlns:nurc="http://www.nurc.nato.int" xmlns:sde="http://geoserver.sf.net" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:it.geosolutions="http://www.geo-solutions.it" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" **numberOfFeatures="0"** timeStamp="2013-03-20T22:36:01.593Z" xsi:schemaLocation="hidden.com http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=DHS%3ATownPoints http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<gml:featureMembers/>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

I think the formatting of my query string `'CODE=A1'` is wrong, so geoServer returns a null set for the queryCollection, meaning the intersection is being performed against a null set. (Note: CODE='A1' works fine if I query Districts directly.)

I have also tried `'CODE='A1''` and some other variations but this nesting always causes an exception similar to the following:

```
Could not parse CQL filter list. Encountered "A1" at line 1, column 92.
 Was expecting one of:
 ")" ...
 "," ...
 "/" ...
 "*" ...
 "+" ...
 "-" ...
 Parsing : INTERSECTS(the_geom,collectGeometries(queryCollection('AU:Districts','the_geom','CODE='A1''))).
```

I have looked at lots of examples but cannot find one with a filter string in the queryCollection function.

Answer (score 1):

```
INTERSECTS(geom, collectGeometries(queryCollection('topp:states', 'the_geom', 'STATE_ABBR=" + "'" + "'" + 'CA' + "'" + "'" + "')))
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. While this is most likely the solution, some explanation would be useful.

Comment: It woudn't let me edit my answer the other day! Building the second expression in this manner "'" + "'" + 'CA' + "'" + "'" allowed me to achieve a text attribute filter to query all points, of my data, within the shape of California.

Answer (score 1):

This source https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/cqlSyntax.html#Escapingcharacters is the best documentation I could find, when I was encountering this CQL problem.

It states that:

> [...] To use a single quotation mark itself in a string literal, escape it using a single quotation mark.

And then shows this example:

```
INSERT INTO cycling.calendar (race_id, race_start_date, race_end_date, race_name) VALUES (201, '2015-02-18', '2015-02-22', 'Women''s Tour of New Zealand');
```

Therefore you could change @Daniels code from:

```
INTERSECTS(geom, collectGeometries(queryCollection('topp:states', 'the_geom', 'STATE_ABBR=" + "'" + "'" + 'CA' + "'" + "'" + "')))
```

to this:

```
INTERSECTS(geom, collectGeometries(queryCollection('topp:states', 'the_geom', 'STATE_ABBR=''CA''')))
```