# Cross layer Filtering in Geoserver still getting error Could not parse CQL filter list. Function not found. Parsing :

Tags: geoserver, wfs, cql-filter, cql, crossfilter

Im trying to apply cross filter to retrieve the layer1 (where des= land) interects with layer2 as follows

```
http://localhost:2211/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&outputFormat=application/json&request=getfeature&typename=ws1:layer1,ws1:layer2&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom,querySingle('ws1:layer1','the_geom','des=land'))&srs=EPSG:4326
```

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770912/cross-layer-filtering-extension-with-more-then-2-filter-query-is-not-working) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55044/geoserver-cql-cross-layer-intersection-failing/153483). I'm still getting an error `Could not parse CQL filter list. Function not found. Parsing : INTERSECTS(the_geom,querySingle('ws1:layer1','the_geom','descr_2=Urban'))`.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: are you trying to find all features where `des=land` or features that intersect with those features. In either case since you are using layer1 in both sides you don't need a cross layer filter.

Comment: I want to find features of layer1 where des=land and intersect with layer2.

Comment: Is the cross layer filtering extension installed? If you check the WFS capabilities document, do you have the "querySingle" function in the function list?

Comment: Ya It's working now, I reinstalled query layer.